# Draw rectangle with dashed border in flex?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, drawrectangle

Draw rectangle with dashed border in flex ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I draw dotted line in flex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995159/how-can-i-draw-dotted-line-in-flex)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in method for this in the drawing API unfortunately. You can Google for some workarounds like this one:
http://www.getw3help.com/2009/10/dashed-rectangle-border-in-flash.html

Hopefully helps,
Rob

Comment: the provided link is out of date or is no longer available!

Answer (score 0):

Personally, if you're using Flex4, I would create a new Skin for whichever component you're trying to style (or just BorderContainer if you just want a blank rectangle).  And from within the skin, I would pogrammically add the 4 dashed lines.